# How to extract transition matrices for smaller intervals than the original transition matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a transition matrix, for example:

\begin{bmatrix}
0.95 & 0.03 & 0.02 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 &0.90  &0.1  &0  & 0\\ 
0 &0.05  & 0.80 &0.1 &0.05 \\ 
 0& 0 & 0.05 &  0.90& 0.05\\ 
 0& 0 &0  &0.1  &0.9 
\end{bmatrix}

Let us say this matrix represents the transition from a vector, for example:
\begin{bmatrix}
22\\ 
9\\ 
13\\ 
18\\ 
10
\end{bmatrix}
to another one, for an interval of 12 years.

I would like to know if it is possible to extract an annual transition matrix from this one. A repeated use of this annual transition matrix (12 times) should of course give me the same end vector.

I have had various ideas that failed including (don't laugh I am not a mathematics student):

- trying to find a matrix that if multiplying 11 times itself would equal the original matrix
- dividing the non-diagonal transitions by 12 and getting the row sums back to 1
- nth roots

To detect if it failed I simply applied any of my ideas and checked if the end vector was the same as obtained through the use of the original matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some necessary and some sufficient conditions, you might look at my paper with Jeff Rosenthal and Jason Wei, "[Finding Generators for Markov Chains via Empirical Transition Matrices,
with Applications to Credit Ratings](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/irw/index.html)", Mathematical Finance 11 (2001), 245-265.

I might note that no such transition matrix with nonnegative entries can exist in your example, but you can get close.

Answer (score 1):

You can carry out an [eigendecomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) of the transition matrix $T$ (using various statistical tools/packages, including R), so that you can express it as
$$T=UDU^{-1}$$
where the $i^{th}$ column of square matrix $U$ is the $i^{th}$ eigenvector, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose entry in row $i$ and column $i$ is the corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda_i$.

Having done this, it is quite straightforward to calculate $T^n$, as this will be
$$T^n=UD^{n}U^{-1}$$
For the annual transition matrix, you would set $n=\frac{1}{12}$, having found matrices $U$ (hence $U^{-1}$) and $D$.

However, as Robert Israel has usefully pointed out, certain conditions need to be satisfied for the entries of $T^n$ to be all positive, which does not hold for your transition matrix.